# Communications devices no longer work properly since Win 10 upgrade

Tags: windows-10

Since I upgraded on July 28, I have had a plethora of problems. I'll do them one by one.

First, when I try to access "Programs and features" I get this error message:

[image]

How can I fix this?

I have been trying to access it through the Win key on the task bar.
I upgraded from Win 7 64 to Win 10 Pro 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using a shortcut for this?

If so you can recreate one like so.

Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type control, click programs, then right click on programs and features and click create shortcut.

If it’s not a shortcut, then you can try resetting the file associations. [As Described in section one here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8703-default-file-type-associations-restore-windows-10-a.html)

It’s also worth trying to starting the service Remote Procedure Call (RPC) Locator Service.

Comment: I have been trying to access it through the Win key on the task bar.

Comment: What happens if you type "appwiz.cpl" into run? (Without Quotes)

Comment: (appwiz.cpl) Control panel, Programs and features (which I was trying to get to) came up. Thanks, although that doesn't address the Win 10 problem.

Comment: What did you upgrade from?

Comment: Win 7 - 64 bit.